# How should I handle mispronouncing words in a coworker's native language and feeling like I'm embarrassing myself?

Tags: communication, language

Similar questions have been asked here before, so I'll try to provide enough detail to explain my specific situation.

### The situation

I am a junior software developer in the United States working on an app project, on a team of a dozen people. We split the team into subgroups of three or four people to tackle specific parts of the app, and I am currently on the backend team working with two other people, "Aaron" and "Bob."

Aaron works in-house with me, but Bob works from overseas in Africa. Bob's first language is Swahili. (Aaron and I are first-language English speakers.) Because he is more comfortable speaking and writing in Swahili, he often names his programs, files and parts of his code after Swahili words, and includes Swahili comments in his code. We also named the app framework after a Swahili word that we found very beautiful and whose meaning he explained to us.

### The thing I'd like advice about

When Bob puts Swahili words in his code and comments, and we're discussing his contributions to the code, I sometimes have had situations where I've pronounced the word verbally. For example, we were discussing one of his functions where he left a joking comment in Swahili, and I read the comment aloud to ask him what it meant.

Almost always I pronounce it wrong, and I feel really terrible when he tells me that I said it horribly wrong. Sometimes he'll try to teach me how to pronounce it correctly, but I can't hear the phoneme differences or can't move my tongue the right way and he gives up on teaching me. When this happens I feel *absolutely horrible.* He never makes a big deal about it and we joke a lot about me being too white to understand, or having terrible pronunciation. But I still feel really awful whenever it happens.

My question is: **how should I handle these situations in the future and/or avoid embarrassing myself by feeling like I'm disrespecting his language?** I always try to apologize when it happens, and I'm studying verbal pronunciation of Swahili phonemes and words so I can do a better job next time, and hopefully be less embarrassing when I try to speak it. But I was wondering if you had any more advice about how to handle awkward language barriers in a graceful way.

Comment: On top of what already said @JoeStrazzere about the fact that all the code should be in English, there should be no jokes in the code (for naming or even comments). This can be distracting when trying to understand the code.

Comment: "Because he is more comfortable speaking and writing in Swahili" think about how Bob must feel with all the words that are not in Swahili. 
Non-English speakers working in English face this issue every day, and we just have to get used to the fact that we speak with a funny accent and sometimes totally pronounce words the wrong way.

Comment: I feel I have been getting a lot of answers to the effect of "make him stop doing this" and I want to be clear: it is never, ever a hindrance to us understanding his comments or functions or anything. He doesn't write code in Swahili, he just occasionally uses a word or two. It's never a genuine barrier to anything and usually he revises himself in English in the production code. I don't think of it as an issue imo.

Comment: `it is never, ever a hindrance to us understanding his comments`... odd... i could have sworn your question stated an example of when you did in fact not understand his comment... also... I really hope you can drop that usually from your second to last sentence (in the comment) without it becoming a lie...

Comment: @Mark Okay, I'll rephrase. I am a junior developer and I am not his manager. I do not want to come off as a judgmental drama queen or lose my job by approaching him about this. I was asking for help with an existing issue, not asking for help with how to be his manager.

Comment: I hate to be 'that guy' but ... shouldn't you really consider to make Bob stop doing this? I say a lot of weird shit while I code, and my colleagues and I joke about in our native language a lot, but none of it ever ends up in my code. It's always professional, and in English, because it goes into a version control system and God knows where it may ever end up. What if your company ever decides to make a snippet open source, or sell it to the client, or there's an audit, and they find "joking comments in Swahili"... that looks a bit ... weird, to say the least, doesn't it.

Comment: May be its just me but... despite your best efforts, if jokes are made about you "being too white", it's no better that jokes being made about him being too black to speak good english!

Comment: "_me being too white to understand_" Can you please elaborate how skin color is of any relevance in this particular case?

Comment: It is not actually Swahili, is it? (Like the made-up names "Aaron" and "Bob.")

Comment: Does "Bob" ever mispronounce English words? Does it offend you?

Comment: Comments and code written in Swahili. And he is worried about mispronunciation.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> how should I handle these situations in the future and/or avoid embarrassing myself by feeling like I'm disrespecting his language?

It sounds like you're going about it the right way, making an honest, good-faith effort to understand Bob's language. Usually people are pretty forgiving if they know you're making an effort to understand their language.

I'm sure a fair number of people wouldn't even try, or insist that Bob write and say everything in English. The fact that you and Aaron are open to the differences speaks well about your attitudes and willingness to work as a true team.

So I wouldn't stress too much about it, and try to have fun with how bad you speak Swahili. I'm sure it can't be easy! You may never master the language, but the more you learn and experience, the easier and less awkward or embarrassing it will become.

One challenge that you will have to overcome is how to make sure that the code is maintainable and understandable by future developers, or developers not on your immediate team. A way to do that could be to provide an English version of the Swahili comment, which could also help you learn the language.

Comment: This is a really nice answer, thank you :) I will continue to try my best to make him feel welcome on the team.

Comment: Do yourself and your company _and your colleague_ a favour and make him feel welcome by helping him speak and write English well.

Comment: This answer completely misses the real issue; that Bob's code is not reviewable or maintainable.

Comment: While it is about the code in the end, @daisy, there's nothing that makes a programming team more productive than good human interaction, and this answer addresses that factor. While Bob's Swahili isn't appropriate in final production code, it may be that, at a subconscious level, he's throwing it in to help bring him into the team and make those personal connections. He's already the outcast since he's not physically in the office and he speaks a different native tongue, by "forcing" others to learn bits of his language he's being included in the team, and it sounds like it's working.

Comment: It might be _better_ if the Swahili were restricted to emails instead of embedded in code (to prevent the possibility of some slipping through into production), but it's serving a good purpose as it stands

Comment: I understand and respect the points of view expressed here and am grateful to everyone for their input, but I am not his manager and this answer directly addressed my question and how I can help in my current power dynamic (i.e. being the lowest-ranking team member and not being able to control what this coworker does). I am marking it as correct.

Comment: @daisy -- not sure that's the *real* issue, but it is definitely a challenge that I should have mentioned. My assumption was that they are already working to mitigate that, but perhaps not. I have added another paragraph addressing this. Not sure it's in the spirit of the question to answer "don't do that."

Answer (score 55):

Was für ein absoluter Unsinn. Wenn er in den USA arbeitet, dann soll er gefälligst die Sprache benutzen, die in den USA verwendet wird. Eines Tages wird dieser Kollege von einem anderen Kollegen ersetzt, der kein Suaheli spricht, und dann stehts Du total auf dem Schlauch. Schlimmer, deine Firma steht auf dem Schlauch. Und dann wirst Du gefragt, warum Du nicht eher was gesagt hast.

And if you didn't understand a bit of this, that's exactly why it's a very, very, very bad idea to let him write code in Swahili.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113341/discussion-on-answer-by-gnasher729-how-should-i-handle-mispronouncing-words-in-a).

Comment: Basically, "when in Rome"? If my half remembered German is correct

Answer (score 11):

Your question presents two problems.

1. Your inability so speak Swahili properly. You are already doing your best. Some sounds in some languages are very difficult for people not familiar with those languages.

Example: there are English sounds almost impossible for Russian people (think of word "her"), and there are Russian sounds almost impossible for English people (example: ["сын"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BD#Russian), meaning "son". That middle "ugly" letter in the middle, looking like "bi", represents one sound - for which there is no graphical representation in English). It is neither good, nor bad. It is just the way it is.

2. The official language in your company, and the code writing rules. There should be a clear rule in the company which language(s) should be used in general in official communication, and which languages should be used when writing comments or choosing identifier names in the code. The purpose of those is to help people understand each other. Considering that Swahili is not at all an "international" language, I expect that the company should forbid it, together with everything else which is not according tot he rules. Module names are also included - they help greatly in understanding and navigating the code.

Of course, choosing the name of an application is a different matter - any language can be used, and any word constructed out of thin air.

It is also a different matter if employees choose to learn other languages, including Swahili and Aramaic - that should be perfectly fine too.

Comment: It's not central to the point you're making, but Certainly Swahili is an international language! It is used for trade across wide swathes of East Africa.

Comment: @OmarL: I understand your point. And depending on the definition, all (most) languages can be declared to be international. :) Maybe we should define the concept of "locally international", or "niche international".

Answer (score 7):

Pronouncing stuff <s>wrongly</s> incorrectly is very very common when learning a foreign language. You are not even trying to learn your co-worker's language, so it is not surprising that you should not get everything right.

You are already going out of your way by trying to learn pronunciation rules, which is nice. You should not feel horrible. Your co-worker probably either likes your wrong pronunciation because it is good for laughs/makes a good topic for small talk/he finds it adorable or whatever, or else he doesn't care. If he would care, he would probably stop using Swahili at some point

The graceful way is just to accept that your pronunciation is going to be wrong 50% of the time or so, and laugh about it. This is normal and by learning some of the simple rules you are probably already avoiding some of the worse mistakes (e.g. mispronouncing the x if your colleague was Chinese)

Comment: Typing things _incorrectly_ is very common even for those who are otherwise reasonably good at a foreign language. "Wrongly" isn't, or at least wasn't, an English word. It is, however, a common misuse from non-native speakers. This isn't intended as an insult or dig, just pointing out a very commonly made mistake in an otherwise well written (in a second, or third... or fourth... language) answer.

Comment: Wrongly is a perfectly valid adverb. Very commonly used in court proceedings "wrongly accused".

Answer (score 5):

Simple, if in doubt, spell the word out instead of attempting to say it.

Comment: Would that come across okay? I just worry that will come off badly if I stop and laboriously spell things out. I don't want to make a big deal about it or make him feel bad for expressing himself.

Comment: It's the normal way of clarifying even for English when people have differing accents. Clear communication is important. He's not expecting you to know Swahili or be able to pronounce it.

Comment: That is totally fair, thank you for the advice!

Comment: "Expressing yourself" requires other people to understand it.  If you don't, he hasn't expressed himself properly.  There's a big difference between using words that have no equivalent in the language (camouflage, ubuntu, hugge, schadenfreude) and simply not communicating in a language you all share.  Also https://dilbert.com/strip/1992-08-03

Comment: Try Dutch instead of Swahili. If English is your only language, you don't have the slightest chance to pronunciate Dutch words correctly because your brain just doesn't know how to produce the sounds you need. Actually, if you try hard enough, you will cause yourself damage. Welsh people have a fighting chance :-)

Comment: On the other hand, German and Turkish are largely sound compatible. A German can take a Turkish text from a book, read it aloud, and a Turkish person will understand it with a bit of effort (even if the German has not the slightest idea what he was saying). The sounds are very similar, and the text <-> speech mapping is mostly identical.

Comment: the OP could just say, 'whats the comment on line 154 mean?'

Answer (score 4):

Technically, I would be fairly concerned about using Swahili in a codebase that will almost certainly be maintained in the future by English speakers, however in general I commend your attitude and behavior here.

One reason, perhaps, that Bob gives up trying to correct your pronunciation is that you're in the middle of, eg, a review not a language tutorial and it's important to make progress on that. Perhaps a separate conversation where you just ask Bob's help on pronunciation and meaning of a word or two?

Also, it's possible that Bob really doesn't have much interest in teaching you basic Swahili, so you might want to try to figure that out. Something like "Hey, Bob, I just sort of realized that I've been asking you quite a few questions about Swahili. I've really enjoyed learning about the language from you, but I just wanted to check that you're actually ok with me doing that?" or something else along those lines.

Remember, too, that the company isn't paying Bob to teach you Swahili and as a remote team member, he may be thinking of that as well. You might check out online resources to learn on your own. There's probably at least a basic pronunciation guide online and maybe some Swahili-English dictionaries. I'm sure Bob would appreciate your willingness to dig in on your own, and you might feel less awkward as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Google Translate can speak!**

Have your phone handy with Google Translate. You can translate in both directions *and* listen.

If he doesn't understand your pronunciation even after copying the sound, just tell him the English word.

[image: Screenshot of Google Translate's "say out loud" feature]

---

P.S.

A personal opinion. I don't think jokes about being "too white" are any more appropriate than being "too black".  Let's leave race out of business matters altogether. It may (or may not) be acceptable between close friends of different skin colours.

Comment: How good is it? Machine translation is usually ... entertaining.

Comment: It's pretty good for individual words. My point is that you can (a) type in Swahili from the code (b) see what it means (c) listen to the word (d) try to pronounce it that way (e) If not understood, use the English word as a help.  I'm not saying it will be infallible but it's probably worth a try - especially in combination with learning the phonetics!

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you :) Me and the coworker joke about things a lot and we have a lot of jabs about my skin color, so it is not an inappropriate or offensive joke to me in context - I always find them funny.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach would be not to worry about it. At least you're attempting to pronounce them, which is more than most would bother to do. And if you say it wrong, or if you simply don't know how to say it, that's the perfect opportunity to ask him to correct you:

"Hey, am I saying this right?" is a perfectly ok phrase to use.